# ACL management with GUI interface

Tags: user-interface, interface, acl, cisco

Are there any interface (GUI) software to manage ACL? Using Cisco ACL, but it's hard to manage with command line. Any ideas?

Basically, need a software tool to manage ACL permissions with GUI instead of command line.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ASDM to manage ACLs for ASA Firewalls.